# JavaScript - Pull out some word from string

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have string like this:

```
const myString = '[12m[99mSOME STRING 1: [bla[bla[88mSOMETHING 2[00m['
```

I want to pull out `"SOME STRING 1"` & `"SOMETHING 2"` from this string in separate variable.
String will be always the same, except part of `"SOME STRING 1"` and `"SOMETHING 2"`.

Because of that I can not use `includes('SOME STRING 1')` for this.

Everything between `[99m` and `:` is the first needed string.

Everything between `[88m` and  `[` is the second needed string.

**Expected result:**

```
const string1 = 'SOME STRING 1'
const string2 = 'SOMETHING 2'
```

Comment: Is this the complete string or sub string?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi this is exactly complete myString, how it looks.

Comment: Try this for string2 : var string2 = str.substring(str.indexOf("[88m")+4,str.indexOf('[00m')); and for string 1: var string1 = str.substring(str.indexOf("[99m")+4,str.indexOf(':'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regex = /\[99m([^:]+).*?\[88m([^[]+)/
myString = '[12m[99mSOME STRING 1: [bla[bla[88mSOMETHING 2[00m['
match = regex.exec(myString)
if (match) {
  var [ ignoreThis, string1, string2 ] = match
}

console.log("string1", string1)
// "SOME STRING 1"
console.log("string2", string2)
// "SOMETHING 2"
```

Explanation:

```
\[99m // Find the exact string "[99m"
(...) // Capture the string that matches the enclosed expression
[^:]+ // Match one or more characters until a ":" character is met
.*?   // Match all characters until the next expression finds a match
\[88m // Find the exact string "[88m"
(...) // Capture the string that matches the enclosed expression
[^[]+ // Match one or more characters until a "[" character is met
```

The output of exec will be `null` or an array of 3 entries. The first entry you can ignore, but the next two correspond to the strings that you capture in the (parentheses).

**Note**: This assumes that your first string will never include a ":" and your second string will never include a "[" character.

[Test this online](https://regex101.com/r/rzI0kc/1)